# Make ActionBar always show in narrow screen mode?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

So that it would look like this in landscape mode & on tablets:

[image: narrow]

instead of this:

[image: expanded]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271853/how-to-control-actionbar-split-programmatically

Comment: Not exactly the same question but Adam's answer is still relevant for this as it is the same type of question.

Comment: @JakeWharton Foursquare somehow did it in the latest incarnation of their app.

Comment: It cannot be done with the native action bar. It cannot be done with ActionBarSherlock (pre-ICS) without modifying the code. Foursquare probably just uses a `TabWidget` or simply a `LinearLayout` that's styled appropriately.