# How to set dynamic created action bar to bottom?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-tabs

To create a navigation bar, I have dynamically create an action bar:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
}
```

And add tabs one by one:

```
    // Create first Tab
    tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new FragmentsTab1());
    // Create your own custom icon
    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.tab1_hdpi);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

The problem is , the action bar is at the top by default. How can I placed it at the bottom? I found `layout_below` may be suitable for this case . However , as it generates dynamically, how can I know its ID? Thanks a lot.

Edited:

After adding split option, it doesn't make any changes, is it due to my action bar is dynamically generated?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
package="com.example.tabtest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

And

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.example.tabtest.MainActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271853/how-to-control-actionbar-split-programmatically

Comment: Don't use bottom tab bars: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: You could create a `split` ActionBar. But that mode makes sense when the top area of the ActionBar is too crowded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your activity tag in the Minifest

```
 uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

Comment: how about using frame layout?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really answered the OP's question.. I'm searching for an answer as well since it looks like the custom bar always gets placed top and default menu bar on bottom if I use this code to bring the custom view:

```
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    // displaying custom ActionBar
    View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom,
            null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

:(

Answer (score 0):

With Android 5.0 API, `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` is deprecated. Unfortunately, this is not very well documented as yet. For details, you can read up this article.

http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/11/18/android-5p0-deprecation-splitactionbarwhennarrow.html