# Align Icon menu in actionBar

Tags: android

I am looking for a solution to align menu icon in the action bar without creating a custom layout.
This question was asked many times, and no one seems able to answer.
Here the last question I found on stack overflow (asked in June 2015): 
"How to center&left&right align the ActionBar icons in Android " [How to center&left&right align the ActionBar icons in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132007/how-to-centerleftright-align-the-actionbar-icons-in-android)

The toolbar is available only for sdk v23 with a very limited features for the previous release.
A custom layout, does not help as you need to manage different screens size and so a number of icons showing on your actionBar.
So any help will be appreciated.

J.