# How to enable Split Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, splitactionbar

I want to create an android application which has 3 sliding tab panel and each of them will 5 button (save,new,delete,exit..).

What I want is exactly as follow:
[image]

I created sliding tab panel.And for 5 button, I added split action bar.But It works as normal split action bar.My AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.belsoft.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Where is my wrong?

Comment: The split action bar pattern is not supported with `Theme.Material` or `Theme.AppCompat`. You would need to create your own `Toolbar` that contains the "split" items and position it in your activity at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### To implement `splitActionBar`:

Just add `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` to your `activity` tag in the`AndroidManifest.xml` like this...

```
`<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">`<br>
```

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220428/placing-my-actionbar-at-the-bottom)

> NOTE:  It is available  ONLY for handset devices with a screen width
>   of `400dp`.

#### To create a custom bottom toolbar:

If you want to set it for all devices, please check my answer (find a post starting with `Creating custom bottom toolbar`) here:

> ## Creating custom bottom toolbar
>
> I've already created a simple app which should demonstrate you how to
>   begin
>
> [image]
>
> #### Creating a custom ViewGroup
>
> Here's my `activity_main.xml` layout file:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:padding="0dp"
>     tools:context="com.example.piotr.myapplication.MainActivity">
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/show_pdf"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="40dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:background="@color/primary_material_light"
>         android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/editText"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
>         android:ems="10"
>         android:inputType="textPersonName"
>         android:text="Name"/>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```
>
> As you can see my parent `ViewGroup` is `RelativeLayout`, which simply
>   allows me to create a view at the bottom of screen.
>
> Notice that I set layout padding to zero (I think: setting layout
>   margin to zero here is not necessary, the same effect). If you'd
>   change it, the toolbar won't use full width and it won't stick with
>   bottom of the screen.
>
> Then I added a Linear Layout with hardcoded height which is:
>
> ```
>           android:layout_height="40dp"
> ```
>
> I wanted it, that my bottom toolbar would take full available width so
>   I set it as `match_parent`.
>
> Next, I added some `ImageButton` views with images from Android
>   library.
>
> There you have two possibilities:
>
> - if you really want to have a toolbar like in above example just remove in every `ImageButton` view this line:
>
>   ```
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>   ```
>
> After removing weights and some buttons you would get a view pretty
>   similar to expected:
>
> [image]
>
> - if you want to take the full width and make every button with the same size use in your project `weight` as in this mine example.
>
> Now let's go to my **AndroidManifest.xml**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest package="com.example.piotr.myapplication"
>           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:supportsRtl="true"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>         <activity
>             android:name=".MainActivity"
>             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>     </application>
> </manifest>
> ```
>
> In that file I'd added as you can see only one additional line:
>
> ```
>          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
> ```
>
> to make sure that device keyboard won't hide my custom bottom toolbar.
>
> From: [How to add a bottom menu to Android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311601/how-to-add-a-bottom-menu-to-android-activity/34422850#34422850)

If you have any question please free to ask.

Hope it help

Comment: thank for your detailed comment.But I dont understand why does toolbar changes places when focusing edittext.When keyboard was appeared, the toolbar changes the places to top of keyboard.How to overcome this.